# Using "grconvertX" and "grconvertY" to find middle and between panel positions in 28 multi-plot case in R

Tags: r, plot

I have **an empty platform for 28 plots:**

```
par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(7, 4))

invisible(lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"))
```

## Question

I'm trying to add some labels. **The positions for labels are shown in the picture below (middle of the panels (*blue points*) and between the gaps (*arrows*) of the panels).**

Using "`grconvertX`" and "`grconvertY`", I'm wondering how to find the positions for all the points I'm showing in the picture below?

For middle positions (***blue points***) along the **x-axis** and **y-axis** the following work perfect:

```
(at <- seq(grconvertX(0 + (1 / 8), "nic"), grconvertX(1 - (1 / 8), "nic"), l = 4))

(at <- seq(grconvertY(0 + (1 / 14), "nic"), grconvertY(1 - (1 / 14), "nic"), l = 7))
```

But for the positions right between the panel gaps (***arrows***) I need help?

[image]

Comment: the arrows would just be at `at[-length(at)] + diff(at)[1L] / 2`

Comment: you already have those, dont you? `abline(v = grconvertX(0:1, 'nic'), xpd = NA)`

Comment: you mean out of order or mis-aligned? you could just `sort(gap.x)` if the former; the text lines up for me and the sorting puts them in the right order from your input

Comment: FYI, you can move around each minor figure after you have created all of them using `par('mfg')`, so for example you could annotate the lower left figure with `par(mfg = c(7, 1)); title(ylab = 'ylab', xlab = 'xlab', xpd = NA, mgp = c(0,0,0))` or the 4th row 4th col figure with `par(mfg = c(4, 4)); points(grconvertX(1, 'nfc'), grconvertY(.5, 'nfc'), pch = 16, xpd = NA)`. but this doesn't do all at once like you seem to be doing

Comment: @rawr, there is just one thing that is still a bit flaky, and that is the use of `line =` in `mtext()`  to place the vector `l` at the gap spaces on side 2 of the plot. So, the problem  is when we move the graphical device (like dragging it to the right to make it larger), then the labels don't move with the plot? Here is what I'm using for this currently: ...

Comment: @rawr ... `mid.y = seq(grconvertY(0 + (1 / 14), "nic"), grconvertY(1 - (1 / 14), "nic"), l = 7) ;
gap.y = sort(c(mid.y[-length(mid.y)] + diff(mid.y)[1L] / 2, grconvertY(0:1, "nic")))` and then:  `l = c('1/10', '1/3', '1', '3', '10', '30', '100', '> 100000') ;
mtext(l, side = 2, at = gap.y, line = 22, cex = .9, font = 2, las = 1)`

Comment: that's normal. If you write the image to pdf or png with the dimensions you want, then everything should be lined up

Comment: if you've calculated all of the coordinates, why not use `text` directly rather than `mtext(line=)` which is relative based on the device dimensions? `text(grconvertX(0, 'nic'), gap.y, l, xpd = NA, adj = 1)`

Comment: there is a subtle difference between `NA` and `TRUE`; I use `NA` all the time, but basically `TRUE` doesn't draw in the `oma` region and `NA` will draw anywhere: `par(oma = c(1,2,1,2)); plot(0); abline(h = 0, xpd = FALSE); abline(h = .5, xpd = TRUE, col = 2); abline(h = -.5, xpd = NA, col = 3)`; technically, these are the plot (black), figure (red), and device (green) regions

Comment: you did all the work for this answer, you should post it and accept it, I think you'll get a new badge for that

Comment: that's not an option as far as I am aware